# Alert On Button Click And Move User To Opened New Tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have Created a Button With Link Which opens in new tab. I have also used javascript to alert.

Currently this code is working perfectly. But After Clicking OK in Alert, user stays on same page. But I Want To Move User To New Opened Tab. Is it possible ?

My Code Is -

```
<form><input type="button" id="anchor1" style="cursor:pointer" value="Click Here" onClick="window.open(href='http://www.google.com')"></form> 

<script type="text/javascript">
  var anchor = document.getElementById('anchor1');
    // or anchor = getElementsByTagName('a') then do ('a')[0]

    anchor.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);

    function doSomething() {
        alert('You Are About To Open New Tab');
    }
</script>
```

Help Needed

Here Is My
**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vaidyamanishjoshi/bR34p/)**

Comment: Why are you using a button and window.open instead of `<a href="..." target="_blank">`?

Comment: As per my website look, Button Needed....

Comment: Use CSS to describe how the website should look, not inappropriate markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is super simple.

You need to remove the `onclick` attribute from the `input` tag.

Then, put your code to open new tab using JS after your `alert` line.

```
<form><input type="button" id="anchor1" style="padding:5px; cursor:pointer" value="Click Here"></form>
```

In your JS code, do this:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('anchor1');

anchor.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);

function doSomething() {
    alert('You Are About To Open New Tab');
    var win = window.open("http://google.com", '_blank');
    win.focus();
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bR34p/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Style the anchor tag by changing the text color to black and changing `text-decoration` to `none`:

```
<button><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click here</a></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form><input type="button" id="anchor1" style="padding:5px; cursor:pointer" value="Click Here" ></form>
```

**JS**

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('anchor1');
// or anchor = getElementsByTagName('a') then do ('a')[0]

anchor.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);

function doSomething() {
    alert('You Are About To Open New Tab');
    window.open(href='http://www.google.com')                
}
```